# What does "cued to your preferred 5 minutes" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

The phrase appeared in the context of an art portfolio requirement.

> Still Images.  Images should be sized at 1024 x 768 @ 72 DPI.  Limit
>   the total number of still images to 20.
>
> Audio & Video. Limit the total
>   time-based media selection to 10 minutes, cued to your preferred 5
>   minutes. [source](https://art.stanford.edu/academics/graduate-programs/masters-program/how-apply)

What does "cued" mean? If I have a 10 minutes video, does it mean that I write "my preferred 5 minutes is 3:20-8:20" somewhere?

Or as Em.♦ suggested, "I expected the spelling queue here, but M-W ([cue (verb 2)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cue)), and Dictionary.com (8/9 [cue](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/cue)) offer relevant entries." If "cued" means "queued", given for example I have 10 minutes video, does it mean I put my preferred 5 minutes before the other 5 less preferred 5 minutes?

Answer (score 1):

'Cue' is not the same as 'queue'.

A 'cue' is an indication of when a segment of audio or video should start. A producer might say, 'Your entry cue is at 3:15'. If I have a long audio track and I want to start playing it for someone in the middle of the track, then I can 'cue' the audio to start at the point that I want that person to hear.

So, if you have a 10 minute selection, you have to choose 5 minutes to present as part of your portfolio. This is your preferred 5 minutes. To 'cue' your presentation, you set up the audio to start playing at the beginning of your preferred 5 minutes. If it's not possible to set the audio up ahead of time, then you can say the 'cue' is at 2:56 of the 10 minute selection.